# Automatic updates of Safari Extensions prompting to quit Safari

Tags: macos, safari, software-update, safari-extensions

Using Safari 15, every morning I open up my Mac and see alert(s) that an extension is trying to reboot Safari:

[image: Close "Safari" to Update]

> Close "Safari" to Update
>
> Click Continue to quit "Safari" and finish updating "ExtensionName".

After clicking "Cancel", the exact same alert then pops up for every other individual extension that want's to update.

How can I prevent these alerts? Can extensions instead be set to update, silently, the next time Safari is quit?

I'm seeing this alert *frequently* for a few extensions that have an aggressive update schedule, and I don't always want to reboot Safari daily.

I would still like for the extensions to update the next time Safari is restarted, but I don't want to be prompted to quit and relaunch Safari every time an extension has an update.

Comment: I've never known Stop the Madness insist on a relaunch - though I'm still on Safari 14.

Comment: I should check @Tetsujin I love that extension and have automatic updates. For me quitting safari is a non event, just quit and relaunch after, though….

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to disable that.
This is one of the downsides of the Safari browser,
AFAIK, the extension doesn't need the restart but the environment can only be updated on lunch/restart, so you get this prompt.

What can be controlled is not checking for updates as often, not installing extensions that update too often or quitting the browser regularly. Safari retains state, so you don’t lose your tabs and items for these updates in my experience.